# Center in a table

Tags: tables

I draw the following table

```
$\begin{table}[h!]
    \[\begin{array}{l|c}
        &0\hspace{0.7cm} 1\hspace{1cm}\dots s \\ \hline
       i&\beta_{0,i}\hspace{1cm} \beta_{1,i+1}\hspace{0.5cm}\dots\hspace{0.5cm}\beta_{s,i+s} \\
      i+1&\beta_{0,i+1}\hspace{0.9cm} \beta_{1,i+2}\hspace{0.5cm}\dots\hspace{0.5cm}\beta_{s,i+s+1}\\
      \vdots&\cdots\cdots\cdots\\\
      j&\beta_{0,j}\hspace{1cm} \beta{1,j+1}\hspace{0.5cm}\dots\hspace{0.5cm}\beta_{s,j+s}
    \end{array}
\]
\caption{Labels need to be placed \emph{after} the caption.}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table}
\\$
```

But 1 is not on the first column, also `$\beta_{0,i}$`. Also 2 is not on the second column. How can I center them?

Comment: Is there any reason for `$\begin{table}`? and `\end{document}\\$`?

Comment: Why all those hand-made horizontal spacings? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you want to use five columns instead of only two:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{l|cccc}
& 0 & 1 & \dots & s \\ \hline
i & \beta_{0,i} & \beta_{1,i+1} & \dots & \beta_{s,i+s} \\
i+1 & \beta_{0,i+1} & \beta_{1,i+2} & \dots & \beta_{s,i+s+1}\\
\vdots & \cdots & \cdots & & \cdots\\\
j & \beta_{0,j} & \beta_{1,j+1} & \dots & \beta_{s,j+s}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Just some improvements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, array}

\begin{document}

  \begin{table}[h!]\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \[ \begin{array}{@{}c|*{4}{c}@{}}
        &0 & 1 & \dots & s \\ \hline
       i &\beta_{0,i} & \beta_{1,i+1} & \dots & \beta_{s,i+s} \\
      i+1&\beta_{0,i+1} & \beta_{1,i+2} & \dots & \beta_{s,i+s+1}\\
      \vdots& \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
      j&\beta_{0,j} & \beta_{1,j+1} & \dots & \beta_{s,j+s}
    \end{array} \]
    \caption{Labels need to be placed \emph{after} the caption.}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use an unnumbered display-math environment (`\[...\}`) to "contain" the `array` environment. Instead, I'd use a `\centering` directive (and place the `array` environment in math mode). To give the array a less-cramped look, consider increasing the value of `\arraystretch` by one third or so.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}
$\begin{array}{@{}c|cccc@{}}
     &0 & 1 & \dots & s \\ \hline
    i&\beta_{0,i} & \beta_{1,i+1} & \dots & \beta_{s,i+s} \\
  i+1&\beta_{0,i+1}& \beta_{1,i+2} & \dots & \beta_{s,i+s+1}\\
  \vdots& \cdots & \cdots & & \cdots \\
    j&\beta_{0,j} &  \beta_{1,j+1} & \dots & \beta_{s,j+s}
\end{array}$
\caption{\texttt{\string\label} must be placed \emph{after} \texttt{\string\caption}}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```